# Java Applet - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, applet

OK so I have this applet which lets a player move his 32x32 character between tiles ... and anytime he is on the edge of the map then MOVES anywhere else... I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Also, when this happens, the character can walk through blocked tiles! However, this only happens on the east and south edges but on the south edge, the character CANNOT walk through blocked tiles upon moving away from the edge.

I don't know how to fix this and maybe you could help me?

Here is an image of me explaining my problem:

[image: applet]

Here is the code:

> /** Tile Generator Programmer: Dan J.
>   Thanks to: g00se, pbl, Manny. Started
>   May 23, 2010
>   **/
>
> import java.awt.*; import
>   java.awt.event.*; import
>   java.applet.Applet; import java.io.*;
>   import java.util.*;
>
> public class tileGen extends Applet
>   implements KeyListener  {
>
> Image[] tiles; // tile arrays   Image
>   player; // player image   int x, y, px,
>   py, tx, ty; // x tile - y tile //
>   player x - player y // tile x - tile y
>     boolean left, right, down, up,
>   canMove, respawn; // is true?     int[][]
>   board; // row tiles for ultimate
>   mapping experience!   final int
>   NUM_TILES = 33; // how many tiles are
>   we implementing?  Label lx, ly; // to
>   see where we are!     int r1, r2,
>   u1,u2,l1,l2,d1,d2;
>
> int lastX, lastY, row, col;     Label
>   lbl1, lbl2, p1, p2;
>
> public void init() {
>
> board = loadBoard();
>
> ```
> tiles = new Image[NUM_TILES];     for(int i = 0;i < NUM_TILES;i++) {
>   tiles[i] = getImage(getClass().getResource(String.format("tiles/t%d.png",
> ```
>
> i)));     }
>
> ```
>     player = getImage(getClass().getResource("player.png"));
> ```
>
> // our player
>           addKeyListener(this);
>           canMove = true;
>           int spawnX = 4;
>           int spawnY = 4;
>           px =0;
>           py =0;
>           lastX = 0;
>           lastY= 0;
>             lbl1 = new Label("LastX", Label.LEFT);
>             lbl2 = new Label("LastY", Label.LEFT);
>
> ```
>       p1 = new Label("X", Label.LEFT);
>       p2 = new Label("Y", Label.LEFT);
>        add(lbl1);
>        add(lbl2);
>
>        add(p1);
>        add(p2);
>        this.setFocusable( true );
> }
>
> private static final HashSet<Integer> BLOCKED_TILES = new
> ```
>
> HashSet();   static {
>   BLOCKED_TILES.add(24);
>   BLOCKED_TILES.add(0);
>   BLOCKED_TILES.add(6);
>   BLOCKED_TILES.add(25);
>   BLOCKED_TILES.add(3);       //add more
>   tiles here    }
>
> public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
>
> if (isInBound(lastX,lastY) == true) {
>     System.out.println("\nYOU WENT OFF
>   THE GRID.\n"); }
>
> ```
>   if (lastX > 0) {        r1 = lastX + 1;
>   }else{      r1 = 0;         }       r2 = lastY;
>
>   u1 = lastX;         if (lastY > 0) {         u2 = lastY - 1;         }else{
>    u2 = 0;
>    }
>
>
>
>   if (lastX > 0) {        l1 = lastX - 1;
>   }else{      l1 = 0;         }       l2 = lastY;
>
>   d1 = lastX;         if (lastY > 0) {            d2
> ```
>
> = lastY + 1;      }else{          d2 = 0;         }
>
> ```
>   right = true;       left = true;        up =
> ```
>
> true;         down = true;
>
> try {         if (blocked(r1,r2) == true)
>   right = false; // we cannot go right
>         if (blocked(u1,u2) == true) up =
>   false; // we cannot go up         if
>   (blocked(l1,l2) == true) left = false;
>   // we cannot go left      if
>   (blocked(d1,d2) == true) down = false;
>   // we cannot go down
>
> ```
>   }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
> ```
>
> dap) { System.out.println("Array Index
>   is Out of Bounds...:(\n" +
>   dap.getCause()); }
>
> if (left == true) {             if
>   (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
>                 left = true;
>                 px = px - 32;
>                 lastX = lastX - 1;          }       }
>
> if (right == true) {            if
>   (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
>   {
>                 right = true;
>                 px = px + 32;
>                 lastX = lastX + 1;      }   }
>
> if (down == true) {             if
>   (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
>                 down = true;
>                 py = py + 32;
>                 lastY = lastY + 1;          }       }
>
> if (up == true) {
>
> ```
>       if (e.getKeyCode() ==
> ```
>
> KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
>                 up = true;
>                 py = py - 32;
>                 lastY = lastY - 1;          }   }
>
> String txtLastX =
>   Integer.toString(px);
>     lbl1.setText(txtLastX);
>
> String txtLastY =
>   Integer.toString(py);
>   lbl2.setText(txtLastY);
>
> String txtLastX1 =
>   Integer.toString(lastX);
>     p1.setText(txtLastX1);
>
> String txtLastX2 =
>   Integer.toString(lastY);
>     p2.setText(txtLastX2); repaint();
>
> } public void keyReleased(KeyEvent
>   e){
>
> } // ignore public void
>   keyTyped(KeyEvent e){} // ignore
>
> public void paint(Graphics g) {
>
> ```
>     for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
>         for (col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
>             int index = board[row][col];
>             g.drawImage(tiles[index], 32 * col, 32
> ```
>
> * row, this);
>
> ```
>         }
>     }
>     if (respawn == false) {
>     g.drawImage(player, px, py, this);    }   if (respawn == true) {
> ```
>
> g.drawImage(player, 0,0, this);
>   System.out.println("Respawned!");
>   respawn = false;  }
>       } // end paint method
>
> ```
>  public void update(Graphics g)
>  {
>       paint(g);
>  }
>
> public int[][] loadBoard() {
>     int[][] board = {
>             { 2,2,24,24,24,24,24,1,3,0,0,0 },
>             { 2,2,24,23,23,23,24,1,3,0,0,0 },
>             { 1,1,24,23,23,23,24,1,3,3,3,1 },
>             { 1,1,24,24,23,24,24,1,1,1,1,1 },
>             { 1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
>             { 5,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,7,1,1,1 },
>             { 6,1,3,1,1,1,3,1,7,7,7,1 },
>             { 6,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,7,3 }
>         };    return board;
> }
> ```
>
> public boolean blocked(int tx, int ty)
>   {   return
>   BLOCKED_TILES.contains(board[ty][tx]);
>   }
>
> public boolean isInBound(int r, int
>   c) {
>       return (r >= 0) && (r < 8) && (c >= 12) && (c < 1); }
>
> } // end whole thing

If this was solved, this would make me **extremely** not sad. :-D I'm sure the problem lies within the map board tile... :\ My guess...

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: 1. Give the stacktrace of the exception. 2. Give only the relevant parts of the code - i.e. near the lines where the exception occurs.

Comment: Anytime I add .printStackTrace I get the error "void is not allowed" or something liek that...

Comment: A bunch of programming style quibbles: `if ... inBound()... "You went off the grid!"` - that sounds like backwards logic. If you're within bounds, you're NOT off the grid, by usual definition. Also, all the `== true` are unnecessary. You can replace `if (right == true)` with `if (right)` and `if (respawn == false)` with `if (!respawn)`.

Comment: @Dan - well figure out that is causing that compilation error!!

Comment: I mean Stephen... that printStackTrace error happens on a java applet skeleton... 
@Carl... I know... but I still didn't understand your possible answer.

Comment: @Stephen: Oh wait... if it's an applet he can't print the stack trace. Oh well, he'll just have to debug the program by watching for things exploding :)

Comment: @Carl - cannot he enable the Java console in his browser?  http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: @Stephen: I stand corrected, I guess. I've never thought to do printlns in an applet, so I don't know if System.err.println() is one of the many things disallowed by applet security.

Comment: @Carl - *"Java Console is a simple debugging aid that redirects any System.out and System.err to the console window. It is available for applets running with Java Plug-in and applications running with Java Web Start."* -- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/console.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote:

```
if (lastX > 0) {        r1 = lastX + 1;
  }else{      r1 = 0;         }       r2 = lastY;

  u1 = lastX;         if (lastY > 0) {         u2 = lastY - 1;         }else{
   u2 = 0;
   }
```

You only increment X if it's already greater than 0? I think you want to make sure it's less than the biggest allowed value for x!

EDIT: In more detail:

Here's your check for going right:

```
if (lastX > 0) {        r1 = lastX + 1;
  }else{      r1 = 0;         }       r2 = lastY;

  u1 = lastX;         if (lastY > 0) {         u2 = lastY - 1;         }else{
   u2 = 0;
   }
```

...and here's your check for going left:

```
  if (lastX > 0) {        l1 = lastX - 1;
  }else{      l1 = 0;         }       l2 = lastY;
```

You're checking the same thing in both cases! That's got to be logically wrong. The first check is, in fact, the reason you get the exception going right: You ask if it's safe to go left, then you go right!

Comment: I'm sorry that made no sense to me. Sorry, English isn't my first language... :(

Comment: But what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Dan - try again.  It makes sense to me.  *"But what do you suggest I do?"*.  His second sentence explains that.

Comment: See my edit. If that doesn't help, just learn to work more carefully.

Comment: @Carl - *"... learn to work more carefully"* ... Agreed.  My impression is that the OP's code is poorly thought out and poorly implemented; e.g the formatting is horrible.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty nicely indented. The formatting on StackOverflow messes it up. The code is thought up just fine, I just think I make it harder than it has to be... :\

Comment: @Dan - don't blame StackOverflow.  The formatting problem is partly the crappy way that you dumped the source code into the edit window, and partly the fact that your source code contains hard TAB characters.  The latter is a huge stylistic sin, in my opinion.  As far as I'm concerned it is too much to expect SO folks to help you with code that they cannot read.  It is **your** responsibility to get the formatting right.

Comment: Um, in the previous codes my indenting was fine and all but when I pasted to Stackoverflow.. it was bad. Maybe I'm just suck at following StackOverflow's style...

Comment: In Dan's defense, there is still a huge and fierce debate over The One True Style among programming professionals, with some of them still making valid arguments for tabs. Eclipse and other IDEs still come with tabbing in their default settings, which I hurriedly change. But in this particular case it's true that, when you're thinking of pasting your code into SO, tabs are a big pain.